# lubuntu 18.10 screen shot

Tags: lubuntu

I upgraded to lubuntu 18.10. Previously I would press the 'prt sc' key and file named something like '2018-08-29-095118_1366x768_scrot.png' would magically exist. I would not have to stop what I was doing to deal with the screen shot. Now there are several windows that popup and want attention.

How do I get the former response to work again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new keybinding for the "Print Screen Key" in Lubuntu 18 uses `lximage-qt -s`.  In order to get the desired behavior you need to change the "Print Screen Key" keybinding to use `scrot`.  This is the screenshot program Lubuntu used to utilize.

This option is under,

Preferences -->  LXQT Settings  -->  Shortcut Keys

Scroll down to "Print" then click on it.  Click the modify button, then delete everything in command box.  After it is empty type in `scrot` then click on the "OK" button.

Everything should work as desired for you now, if not then open the terminal and make sure `scrot` is installed with `sudo apt-get install scrot`.